# Sudo issue was closed - reason?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question, and it was closed and deleted.

I ask myself: Who hates progress, improvements and changes?

https://serverfault.com/questions/846453/alterantive-to-sudo-which-allows-regular-expressions

Answer (score 5):

Quite simple: Questions asking for product recommendations are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on ServerFault. You are asking for a product recommendation, so the question was closed and subsequently deleted by an automatic process.

Comment: Imagine you are a new comer. You don't know if there is a hidden feature or if it is only available via an alternative product. There are use-cases and the use-case generates the question. A new comer does not know if an alternative is needed or not. In this case I am sure that the standard command does not help. ... I don't like this distinction between softwarerec and other sites ...

Comment: @guettli While we're imagining we're newcomers, please imagine you're an old hat here who's seeing their thousandth "I didn't read the basic rules" post.

Answer (score 5):

We don't generally hate progress, improvements and changes. Most of the answers here on Serverfault actually leads to improved configurations, towards best practices instead of workarounds.

Your question was probably closed because it was – and still is – a Q*uestion asking for product recommendations*, that are generally off-topic. The reason for which it is off-topic is clear and doesn't change. It also already answers your meta question.

If you supposedly *had* a better alternative for `sudo` and had doubts whether you should use it or not (against your specified needs), or problems with its configuration, it would have been clearly on-topic.